# Delphi - using the calendar component

Tags: delphi, date, ms-access, delphi-7

I'm trying to use a calendar as an input to add new entries to a database. The problem is, `calendar1.CalendarDate;` returns a string value but the database (using Access) has a date format. Is there any function to convert a string to date format or am I using the wrong function (`.CalendarDate`)?

The version is Delphi 7.

Answer (score 0):

The `TCalendar.CalendarDate` property returns a `TDateTime`, not a `String`.  You can assign that to a `TField.AsDateTime` property, for instance.